# extending cardview class show white rectangle around the card

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-cardview

I'm extending CardView class because I want to create custom view for each row of my list view.
this is my xml layout

```
<com.mojiapps.myquran.items.TranslationDownloadItemView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
android:gravity="right"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
...

</com.mojiapps.myquran.items.TranslationDownloadItemView>
```

and this is my java class

```
public class TranslationDownloadItemView extends CardView {


public TranslationDownloadItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TranslationDownloadItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private void init() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.translation_type_row, this);
...
}
...
}
```

and this is the result

[image]

can anybody help me?

Comment: Why you use CardView at all if you have custom view? Just pass layout to in RecyclerView Adapter onCreateViewHolder

Comment: I don't use RecyclerView and if I don't use cardview I should create a selector drawable to have cardview style

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue setting the CardView background to something transparent. I solved it setting a non-alpha color.

Try to set your `android:foreground` to something without alphas.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by setting white background to `CardView`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
```

Or you can set cardElevationto 0dp but this would disable shadow

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/trans_black_darker"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question, but I wanted to point out a simpler method to inflating in a child of View (so often overlooked).

Instead of:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
inflater.inflate(R.layout.translation_type_row, this);
```

Try this:

```
inflate(getContext(), R.layout.translation_type_row, this);
```

Using the static View **inflate()** is the cleanest and most efficient way to go; you don't need a LayoutInflater.